# Bash passing a variable from function

Tags: bash, function, variables, echo

I'm trying to find out whether there is a Screen running or not with a function. To make it more simple ive written a little test script:

```
#! /bin/bash

function status()
    {
        if [ $a==1 ] 
        then
            echo 1
        else
            echo 0
        fi
    }

a=1
echo $(status)
a=0
echo $(status)
status
if [ $(status)==0 ]
then
    echo "Success"
else
    echo "Fail"
fi
```

The Output is:     1;1;Sucess

But it should be:  1;0;Sucess

What am I doing wrong?

thanks alot, chrys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need spaces around `==`

so: `if [ $a==1 ]` should be:

```
if [ "$a" == 1 ]
```

and

```
if [ $(status) == 0 ]
```

Comment: Also, `==` is not defined. It may work in bash, but correctly it's only a single equals sign `=`

Comment: @JoSo The question is tagged `bash` and the code in question begins with `#!/bin/bash`.  I'm not sure if the comment was warranted.

Comment: @devnull: From `bash` manpage: "`=` should be used with the test
command for POSIX conformance."

Comment: @JoSo Hmm.. I _assume_ that you always start `bash` by saying `bash --posix`.

Comment: @devnull: Nope, I use bash only interactively, and stay sane with `sh` for scripts :)

Comment: @JoSo So might make more sense to follow the `sh` tag instead of `bash`.  No?

Comment: @devnull: Come on, this was just meant to educate what's the portable standards version. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

Remove spaces around == , included quotes and removed a call for status

```
#! /bin/bash

function status()
    {
        if [ $a == '1' ]
        then
            echo 1
        else
            echo 0
        fi
    }

a=1
echo $(status)

a=0
echo $(status)

if [ $(status) == '0' ]
then
    echo "Success"
else
    echo "Fail"
fi
```